# Initialize array of arrays with a set array length

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I want to initialize an array of arrays like in java:

```
int[][] arrPos=new int[16][48];
int[][] arrPosOther=new int[16][48];
```

and I can set a row array value like this:

```
arrPos[0]=arrPosOther[0];
```

and I can set a cell value like this:

```
arrPos[1][0]=125;
```

but in C#, I can declare only like this:

```
int[][] arrPos=new int[16][];
```

can not set the column value in the initialization.

Comment: In C# you have 2 options - multi-dimentional array `int[,]`, `int[,,]` or jagged array `int[][]`. These 2 will cover all array needs

Comment: I know the jagged type, but I want to initialize an array of arrays like arr[255][255], I can't image that scene.

Comment: If you ask me, this- `arr[255][255]` doesn't make any sense because you declaring 256-member array of `255`. The second `[]` is where another array goes, not some integer

Comment: @AndyFong it looks like you are asking for something different than you've posted (possibly "how to represent 2d array as 1d array") - consider asking *new* question that shows what you are looking for. Consider accepting Alex Bell's answer that shows syntax of what is currently posted in the question.

Comment: I would agree with Alexei Levenkov. It's probably better to post another question (if any) because this one has been thoroughly answered. Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to find a way to initialize Jagged array in c#: please refer to the following example:

```
int[][] jaggedArray2 = new int[][] 
{
    new int[] {1,3,5,7,9},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6},
    new int[] {11,22}
};
```

The short form for the same sample is shown below:

```
int[][] jaggedArray2 =
{
    new int[] {1,3,5,7,9},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6},
    new int[] {11,22}
};
```

You can also perform the initialization in several steps:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
jaggedArray[1] = new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6 };
jaggedArray[2] = new int[] { 11, 22 };
```

And, apparently, you can implement a sort of `for` or `foreach` loop in order to populate the array from some data structure. More reading available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Also, you should probably consider a use of multidimensional array, like `int[,]` (the C# syntax in this case is different from Java lang).
Hope this will help.

Comment: But if the row or column value is huge,this initialization type is unconvenient

Comment: If you don't want the array to be jagged, why not just use a 2d array instead? You'll need to use a for-loop otherwise.

Comment: I've tried, but in that way, I can not use single index to visit a row  array in C#, but in java it works.

Comment: I have extended the answer with more samples for your convenience. You can use any of them, depends on your requirements/preferences. Also, consider the suggestion made by @Blorgbeard pertinent to your case. Best regards,

Comment: Really thanks! Finally I used the jagged array and use a for-loop to init the 2nd dimension

Comment: You are very welcome. Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax you are looking for.

One statement option could be

```
 int[][] arrPos = Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(_ => new int[length]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Alexei, you posted good example, but from the discussion thread it seems like OP is actually looking for multidimensional array int [,] (AFAIC, they don't have that syntax in Java). Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell - maybe... On other hand till OP edits question to match comments your answers stands. Feel free to edit in this sample into your answer. (I've also added comment on thee question so OP probably should ask new question clarifying what the goal is).

Comment: yeah, I agree: it's better to post another one if still any questions left. Thx and regards,